# Samsung Note 4 charging cable (ECB-DU4AWE vs. ECB-DU4EWE)

Tags: samsung, charging, samsung-galaxy-note, samsung-galaxy-note-4

Unfortunately, my charging cable for my Samsung note 4 is broken, so I have to buy a new one. I have seen two different charging cables:

- ECB-DU4**A**WE which is 1m long
- ECB-DU4**E**WE which is 1.5m long

Is the length the only difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the data on internet, there appears to be no difference. One thing that could be different is the thickness , measured in [AWG](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge). *Lower*  the AWG figure, lesser resistance is offered and hence better suited for quicker charging. In the absence of figures one has to assume they are both of same AWG, which leaves *length* as the only differentiator.

Since electrical resistance is directly proportional to length, the 1 m cable would permit more current flow and hence is preferred